# Do we need a load balancer on replicated servers?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

Let's say ZooKeeper support replication / redundancy. In replicated set it have
server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
where zoo1, zoo2, zoo3 is address.

My question is, how does a client know which server (zoo1, zoo2 or 3) it is going to connect to? Do we need to put a load balancer so it will redirect the request to any one of the servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zookeeper clients take a connection string, which includes a list of all server:port combinations it should try to connect to.  You don't need a load balancer, since the clients are supposed to be smart enough to balance themselves.

For other applications, you may need a load balancer.  For example RabbitMQ clients do not try to connect to multiple hosts, so it's necessary to have one in a clustered environment.